# Weird problem with st_polygon in the sf package

Tags: r, polygon, linestring, sf

I would like to create a simple polygon using the `sf` package.

From my understanding, I have to create a two column matrix where the last row is identical to the first one to close the ring of the polygon.

```
p1 <- structure(c(0.424084334649542, 0.316800956453136, 0.394125036134903, 
                 0.424084334649542, 0.646053530054886, 0.608338100572382, 0.851623048730609, 
                 0.646053530054886), .Dim = c(4L, 2L))
```

The matrix `p1` has the form that I want

```
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.4240843 0.6460535
[2,] 0.3168010 0.6083381
[3,] 0.3941250 0.8516230
[4,] 0.4240843 0.6460535
```

If I try to create a polygon with this data I got this error

```
st_polygon(p1)
```

> Error in MtrxSet(x, dim, type = "POLYGON", needClosed = TRUE) :
>   is.list(x) is not TRUE

However for linestrings it works

```
st_linestring(p1)
```

> LINESTRING (0.4240843 0.6460535, 0.316801 0.6083381, 0.394125
>   0.851623, 0.4240843 0.6460535)

Anyone knows why?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake!

I forgot to include `p1` into a list.

This code works

```
st_polygon(list(p1))
```

> POLYGON ((0.4240843 0.6460535, 0.316801 0.6083381, 0.394125 0.851623,
>   0.4240843 0.6460535))